# How to add Progress bar for shell scripts having few commands?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh, zsh

I am writing a **shell script** with some commands. I want to add a Progress bar to it.

For Example-

```
Command 1 #Progress bar at 25%
Command 2 #Progress bar at 50%
Command 3 #Progress bar at 75%
Command 4 #Progress bar at 100%
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am using Bash terminal of linux and want to display progress bar in terminal.

Comment: pv might be of help to you.

Comment: Which OS / Shell ?  tsh, csh, bash, ksh, powershell etc  ?

Comment: Are you looking for graphic (X) progress bar, or terminal based progress bar ?

Comment: @jim I am using Linux Mint and Bash shell

Comment: @dash-o I am looking for terminal based progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many solutions  the easiest way is using externat commands like pv

```
du -h /var | tail -2 | pv
```

a nicer way can be using functions in your script for the bar display :

```
echo -ne '#####                     (33%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '#############             (66%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '#######################   (100%)\r'
echo -ne '\n'
```

or even better using the rolling spin :

```
sp='/-\|'
printf ' '
while true; do
    printf '\b%.1s' "$sp"
    sp=${sp#?}${sp%???}
done
```

you launch the task as background & bars and/or spin as foreground
of course you make conditions or traps on signals to stop it at end of task/command.

Comment: `echo -ne` would be more safely written as `printf`. The POSIX specification doesn't define how `-n` behaves, and any shell that treats `-e` as something other than content to be printed is breaking the standard outright. (bash does this out-of-the-box, but it's also capable of being configured to be standard-compliant, either at compile-time or at runtime via environment variables or `shopt` options, so `echo -e` isn't reliable even if the shell is 100% certain to be bash).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n 'Progress: [--------------------]'
sleep 1     # <- Command 1
echo -ne '\rProgress: [#####---------------]'
sleep 1     # <- Command 2
echo -ne '\rProgress: [##########----------]'
sleep 1     # <- Command 3
echo -ne '\rProgress: [###############-----]'
sleep 1     # <- Command 4
echo -e '\rProgress: [####################]'
```

Comment: Same comment I put on the other answer applies. `echo -n`, `echo -e`, and `echo -ne` are all more safely replaced with `printf`; this will improve not only portability to other shells, but also reliability in contexts where you know the shell is bash but don't control the set of active environment variables.